# how to retain the previous echo value and echo another one below it in php?

Tags: php, session

I am creating a shopping cart, but my echo did not appear as expected. im not sure where did i go wrong.

this is my Product detail page,

```html
<form  action="shoppingCart.php?addToCart=<?php echo $key ?>" method="post">
    <select name="quantity">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="<?php echo $key ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="addToCart" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

this is my shopping cart php code:

```html
<?php
        session_start();

            
            


            if (isset($_SESSION['shoppingCart'])) {
                $_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = [];
            }
            

            if (isset($_POST['addToCart'])) {
                echo "Product: " . $_POST['productName'] . "<br/>";
                $count = count($_SESSION['shoppingCart']);
                echo "count: $count<br/>";
                $_SESSION['shoppingCart'][$count]['productName'] = $_POST['productName'];
                $_SESSION['shoppingCart'][$count]['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                
            
                echo "<h3>Your Cart</h3>";
                if (empty($_SESSION['shoppingCart'])) {
                    echo "your cart is empty<br/>";
                } else {
                    
                    foreach ($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $key => $names) {
                        
                        echo "cart($key) = product: " . $names['productName'] . "-Quantity: " . $names['quantity'] . "<br/>";
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            ?>
```

i can only echo out this in add to cart page.

Product: Koala

count: 0

**Your Cart**

cart(0) = product: AkwardKoala-Quantity: 1

how can i acheive this,

**Your Cart**

cart(0) = product: Koala-Quantity: 1

cart(1) = product: cat-Quantity: 3

cart(2) = product: fish-Quantity: 1

Comment: Why do you need the key in both the `action` URL and the hidden input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
        if (isset($_SESSION['shoppingCart'])) {
            $_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = [];
        }
```

You're emptying the session variable when it's already set. I think you want to initialize it when it's **not** set. So it should be:

```
        if (!isset($_SESSION['shoppingCart'])) {
            $_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = [];
        }
```

Then you can add the new item to the cart, and all the old items will be retained.